# Making Pojo Class of XML response for Retrofit Android

Tags: java, android, xml-parsing, retrofit2

I have been developing android applications for the last 2 years but today I am stuck on a strange issue. I am calling an API from my android application using retrofit 2.1.0 and its response is in XML. This is is the first time, I am having such an issue but I don't how to make POJO class of XML. I did a lot of R&D but I couldn't understand their logic. This is the response of API. Can u guide me to make POJO class of this response so that I can use it in my retrofit class

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
    <S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <S:Body>
            <ns2:cardtransactionResponse xmlns:ns2="http://webservices.serfinsa.sysdots.com/">
                <return>{"cliente_trans_terminalid":"00299997",
                         "cliente_trans_trantime":"083307",
                         "cliente_trans_referencia":"020708000010",
                         "cliente_trans_networkid":"024",
                         "cliente_trans_autoriza":"016998",
                         "cliente_trans_respuesta":"00",
                         "cliente_trans_trandate":"0725",
                         "cliente_trans_tipomensaje":"000000",
                         "cliente_trans_auditno":"000010",
                         "cliente_trans_monto":"000000002300"}</return>

            </ns2:cardtransactionResponse>
        </S:Body>
    </S:Envelope>
```

Comment: jackson-xml-serialization-and-deserialization check sample https://dzone.com/articles/using-jaxb-for-xml-with-java

Comment: i am not understanding it